# Цвет и дизайн заголовка

Tags: python, tkinter

Возможно ли поменять цвет заголовка через Tk в Python?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
import tkinter

foregroundColor = "#eee"
backgroundColor = "#555"
titleColor = "цвет, нужный для заголовка"

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.configure(background = titleColor)
root.title("Launcher")
root.geometry("600x400")

version = tkinter.Label(text = "Engine 5.1 - Launcher (0.01)", fg = foregroundColor, bg = backgroundColor)
version.place(relx = .2, rely = .1, relwidth = 0.6, relheight = 0.1)

root.mainloop()
```